# Any possible way to wait for ajax post request to complete then continue

Tags: jquery

I am writing a ajax function, in which I need to wait until the ajax give me the result,  and then continue my code. But it is not working. I searched in stackoverflow and most of the user says use "async: false", but this is not working for me. :(
What I am doing wrong?

```
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 30000,
            type: "POST",
            data: {user: 'stack'},
            url: "/userdata.php",
            error: function (error)
            {
                console.log('eer');
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not continue your code inside success function ? success function is executed after async call.

Comment: This code is called by another function and need to send a response.. But that function miss it.

Comment: You can do what @levi suggested or perhaps use a callback.

Comment: Please add to your question the calling function and a step by step case. This will make it easier for people to guess what you're after.

Comment: can you add that function too which is calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `jquery ajax when`.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

You could put the code that should continue after the AJAX call in the success/error functions or you can use Promises. By default, `$.ajax()` returns a promise object which you can use. See http://api.jquery.com/promise/